# Critical sections in Java using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I was hoping to solve the critical section problem in Java. The first process enters into infinite while loop which should end with the change in control between the states, which leads to the turn variable being reset. But the second thread does not seem to do its job. Can anyone please tell me why and how to fix it?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


class ty{
    class Control{
        public volatile AtomicBoolean turn=new AtomicBoolean();  
    }
    final Control control=new Control();
}

class newthread implements Runnable{
    Thread g;
    ty t=new ty();
    newthread(){
    g=new Thread(this,"hello");
    g.start();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        while ((t.control.turn).get()==false){   
            try {
                g.sleep(2000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(newthread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("process "+t.control.turn+"is executing");
        }
        System.out.println("process "+ t.control.turn+ " is executing");
        (t.control.turn).compareAndSet(false, true);
    }
}

class newthreadt implements Runnable{
    Thread g;
    ty t=new ty();
    newthreadt(){   
        g=new Thread(this,"hello1");
        g.start();
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){  
        while ((t.control.turn).get()==true){ 
            try {
                g.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(newthreadt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("process "+t.control.turn+"is executing");
        }
        System.out.println("process "+t.control.turn+"is executing");
        (t.control.turn).compareAndSet(true, false);
    }
}

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int turn=0;
        newthread f;
        newthreadt g;
        new newthread();
        new newthreadt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it is very difficult to read the code in its current form

Comment: You can remove as much code as possible. esp code which doesn't do anything. I also suggest you use Java Code Conventions like `TitleCase` class names.

Comment: I strongly suggest avoiding creating threads in your constructor or calling static methods like `Thread.sleep` on instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do half the things you are doing, but one thing you really need to do is to share the control.  At the moment each thread creates its own Control which means the threads are not interacting.

So after you format your code and remove half it what you don't need, and share the AtomicBoolean it is much closer to working.